# Where to place business logic layer in relation to data access while providing unit testability by dependency injection?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, unit-testing, dependency-injection

I am looking for a way to have a separate layer of business logic in a MVC4 app with Entity Framework, without having to inject my (real or fake) database context in it. Right now we have a fake and real database context that derives from `IContext`, a repository `Repository` and a controller `MyController`. The `IContext` is injected into a controller, and also the repository, with this pattern:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    readonly Repository _repo;

    /// <summary>
    ///     Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="Controllers.MyController"/> class which
    ///     makes use of the real Entity Framework context that connects with the database.
    /// </summary>
    public MyController()
    {
        _repo = new Repository();
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="Controllers.MyController"/> class which
    ///     can make use of a "Fake" Entity Framework context for unit testing purposes.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="db">Database context.</param>
    public MyController(IContext db)
    {
        _repo = new Repository(db); 
    }
    (...)
}
```

This is set up like that since it is the repository which has method that access the database and need a fake context, while the unit tests aim at the controllers and needs to be instantiated.

Now I am looking for a way to add a business logic class to the project where methods will be put that have business logic. These methods will need information obtained from the data access layer (`Repository`) as well.

It feels a bit strange to also inject the `IContext` for the `Repository` in this business logic layer with the above pattern. E.g.,

```
BusinessLogic(IContext db) 
{
     _repo = new Repository(db);
}
```

I see two ways to avoid this problem:

1. Call the repository in the controllers and use data obtained as parameters to methods in the business logic layer.
2. Inject anyway.

I am looking for a good idea to set up the business logic layer in relation to data access and provide unit testability, preferably without having to inject the database context in every class.

Hope someone can provide me with some insights. Thanks.

Comment: @LiverpoolsNumber9 Ah nice. So while testing then I first instantiate a "fake" repository, inject that fake repo into the business logic, and then instantiate a controller with that business logic?

Comment: You need to interface your repository. Why you haven't done that I don't know. Then inject IRepository into your business logic. Interface that too in case you need to mock it. Also only inject IBusinessLogic into your controller.

Comment: Yes, sorry first comment was rubbush so deleted. 2nd comment makes sense I hope :)

Comment: Why is an interface to the repository needed? The only thing that needs to be faked is DbContext.

Comment: Ah I found a good example of separating business logic and repository [here](http://www.arrangeactassert.com/asp-net-mvc-controller-best-practices-%E2%80%93-skinny-controllers/).

Comment: Because it makes it easier to mock, re-implement etc. Mocking DbContext is pointless. You're never gonna test it because MS already have.

Comment: @LiverpoolsNumber9 It is used by adding collections to the context which represent the database tables, to check if the correct information is updated. Following the idea of here: http://romiller.com/2012/02/14/testing-with-a-fake-dbcontext/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have your EF context , which inherits from IContext, or DbContext if you want to use EF6:

```
    public class UserContext : DbContext 
    {
        DbSet<User> users { get; set; }        
    }
```

You don't want to inject your context directly into your Controler.

Use a Service / DAO / Repository that takes a IContext / DbContext instance in the constructor
and handles the data access.
In my example I use an IUserService that takes a context and returns a user by ID.

```
    public interface IUserService
    {        
       User GetUserByID(int userId);        
    }

    public class UserService : IUserService
    {

      private readonly UserContext _context;
    
      //Inject your mock or real context here
      public UserService(UserContext context)
      { 

         this._context = context;

      }

      //Implement IUserService
      public User GetUserByID(int userId)
      {  
          _context.Users.Where(u=>u.ID==userId).FirstOrDefault();
      }

    }
```

Then inject the Service via interface into your controller.

```
  public class UserController : Controller
  {

     private readonly IUserService _service;

     //Consider using a Dependency injection framework e.g. Unity
     public UserController(IUserService service)
     { 
        this.service = service;
     } 

     //The method that is tightly coupled to the view and uses the service
     [HttpGet] 
     public ActionResult GetUserByID(int id)
     {
          return View(_service.GetUserById(id));
     }
 }
```

Also, consider using a mocking framework to mock your context e.g. Moq

```
[TestMethod]
public void UserServiceTest()
{
        //Initialize your Mock Data
        var testDataUser = new List<Users> 
        { 
            new User{
                                ID = 1,
                                Name = "MockUser"
            }
        }.AsQueryable();

         //Initialize the Mock DbSet
        var mockSetUser = new Mock<DbSet<User>>();
        mockSetUser.As<IQueryable<User>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(testDataUser. .Provider);
        mockSetUser.As<IQueryable<User>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(testDataUser .Expression);
        mockSetUser.As<IQueryable<User>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(testDataUser .ElementType);
        mockSetUser.As<IQueryable<User>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(testDataUser .GetEnumerator());

         //Initialize the mock Context
        var mockContext = new Mock<UserContext>();

        //Return the mock DbSet via the mock context
        mockContext.Setup(c => c.Users).Returns(mockSetUser.Object);

        //Create the service and inject the mock context
        var userService = new UserService(mockContext.Object)
        
        //Test your context via the service
        var user = userService.GetUserByID(1);

        Assert.AreEqual("MockUser", user.Name);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what we are doing now. Only I decided to call the `Service` a `Manager`. We will see if we will use `Moq`.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with [GMich](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4308529/gmich).  As well...
There should be hard boundaries between your layers.  It could look something like this:

IUserController <-- IUserProcessor <-- IUserRepository <-- IContext

Your DI and constructors could be:

```js
public UserController(IUserProcessor userProcessor){...}
public UserProcessor(IUserRepository userRepository){...}
public UserRepository(IContext context){...}
public MyAppContext(string connectionString){...}
```

It is also convenient to create containers which encapsulate business logic and repositories as properties.  For example:

```js
public class RepositoryContainer : IRepositoryContainer
{
  private readonly IContext _context;
  
  private IUserRepository _userRepository;
  private IUserProfileRepository _userProfileRepository;
  
  public RepositoryContainer(IContext context)
  {
    if (context == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
    
    _context = context;
  }
  
  public IUserRepository UserRepository
  {
    get 
    { 
      return _userRepository = _userRepository ?? new UserRepository(_context); 
    }
  }
  
  public IUserProfileRepository UserProfileRepository
  {
    get
    {
      return _userProfileRepository = _userProfileRepository ?? new UserProfileRepository(_context);
    }
  }
}
```

And to clarify, when using this approach, there could be a IBusinessLogicContainer as well.  We wouldn't want to join BL and Repo objects in the same container.

Comment: Thank you. This is indeed very similar to the approach I'm using now. What is the advantage of using a container? And what is the reason everyone uses interfaces for the repository and services/managers? I don't see now how that can improve unit-testability.

Comment: You should always code against interfaces instead of concrete implementations.  1) Keeps your code scalable, 2) Keeps your code testable.  When unit testing, you should be testing one method. And if that method uses a dependency(s), the dependency should be mocked. Otherwise, you are actually testing the method and its dependencies.  Especially when your method relies on things such as a database.  You wouldn't want to run unit tests against a live database.

Comment: Also, with repository containers, you can decide to have all repositories share the same IContext which makes it much easier to encapsulate multiple repository actions into one database transaction.

Comment: I have a `IContext` which is injected into the repository so the database connection can be stubbed. Right now I see no reason to have interfaces for the managers or repositories. I do see an advantage in using a repository container for multiple transactions into one database transaction (I can feel that this is possible, I have no clear view on how to implement it though). Thanks.

Comment: The RepositoryContainer code I posted shows the implementation.  If you are writing unit tests against your managers, although the IContext is mocked, you are still tainting you manager test with repository code.  So, mock the repository when testing the manager.  Mock the IContext when/if testing the Repository.